# Is there a function that works like chr but fails if its argument is not a Unicode scalar value?

Tags: haskell, unicode

I was thinking that there should be a function that works like [`chr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:chr) but fails in the case when its argument is not a Unicode scalar value.

I usually write my own function this way:

```
toUnicode :: Int -> Maybe Char
toUnicode x
  -- Ranges from "The Unicode Standard".
  -- See definition D76 in Section 3.9, Unicode Encoding Forms.
  | x >= 0      && x <= 0xD7FF   = Just (chr x)
  | x >= 0xE000 && x <= 0x10FFFF = Just (chr x)
  | otherwise                    = Nothing
```

But it would be nice if there's a better way to do that.

Comment: Your function seems fine.  If you're looking for a standard library function, if it was anywhere, it would be in either `Data.Char` or maybe `Data.Text`, and I don't see it there.

Answer (score 1):

is this is something you use to do, you can create an adds modules, like `Data.Char.Adds` and import whenever you want. It seems like it doesn't exist in the present. I cannot see another workaround.